# How to SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len

Tags: php, mysql

What is the PHP code please to `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000` 
or `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=15000` with MySQL?

Comment: That's just SQL. So just execute it.

Answer (score 7):

Could you just do a query?

```
$query = 'SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000';

mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this as a Query using `mysql_query()` from PHP. It works for me.

You have to do this as root, otherwise, will be `falter error: Access denied.`